# Windows 7 USB port not working after Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, usb, windows-10-preview

I have a PC with three HDD. I've got Windows 7 running perfectly on one of them. Some days ago I installed Windows 10 Technical Preview on my second HDD. Windows 10 also works perfectly but when I boot my PC it asks me if I want to boot Windows 7 or Windows 10, and as I said, Windows 10 works perfectly, but now when I choose Windows 7 it boots normally till my login screen where it disables all USB ports so I can't login. What should I do? Will it start working if I uninstall Windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install Windows 7 on another hard drive(another partiton may work but not tested). After install and when i came to the desktop on new windows 7 I restarted  my computer and launch old windows 7 and it worked

Im not 100% sure it works for every one but it worked for me twice.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, If you are dual booting a stable-ish but still in beta OS, there is the possibility that Windows 10 will break Windows 7. Let me point out that **this shouldn't happen, as Windows 10 is stable.** Another possibility is that you have a RAID (Redundant Array of Independent/Inexpensive Disks) and Windows 10 has written over the Windows 7 version of the USB drivers. OR, Windows 10 has written over some of Windows 7s files.

If this has happened, you really have no option than that of reinstalling Windows 7 if you need it, or wiping Windows 7 and only using Windows 10.

Comment: well that sucks..But thx for an answer

Comment: I know, trust me. this happened to me, and I was really annoyed.

Comment: is it possible to insert W7 disk and repair insted of reinstall?

Comment: It would be easier to do a reinstall, but a repair **could** work, although I wouldn't advise it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case:

In BIOS, changing xHCI Mode "Smart Auto" to "Auto" solve the problem.